# Javascript error with Returning the provided string with the first letter of each word capitalized

Tags: javascript, string

I am working on solving a basic coding challenge, I feel like my code SHOULD work.  But  this line is not reassigning correctly "`str[i][0] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();`"

I just don't know why this is working this way in Javascript, I think I've solved this same problem in Ruby without issue.  Any tips or links on where to learn more about how this works in Javascript would be MUCH appreciated!

This is the challenge:

Return the provided string with the first letter of each word capitalized.

```
function titleCase(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i][0] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }
    str = str.join(" ");
    return str;
}
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

Comment: JavaScript strings are **not** arrays (like in `C`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, Strings are immutable objects. So, once a String object is created, you cannot change individual characters in them, but you need to create a new String object. So, you are better off with something like this

```
function titleCase(str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].substring(1);
    }
    return str.join(" ");
}
console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
# I'm A Little Tea Pot
```

The key here is,

```
str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].substring(1);
```

We are taking each word's first character, converting that to upper case and then concatenating it with the rest of the actual string and storing the newly created String object back in the `str` array.

---

Apart from that, if you prefer the functional touch to solve this problem, you can do

```
function titleCase(str) {
    return str.toLowerCase().split(" ").map(function(currentPart) {
        return currentPart.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + currentPart.substring(1);
    }).join(" ");
}
```

The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function will invoke the function passed to it, with each element from the `split` array and returns another array. Finally we join all of the elements together with `join`.